# Basic syslog confusion

Tags: linux, logs, syslog

When an application logs using syslog does it mean that it stores the logs somewhere under /var/log? Or can it be elsewhere as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/var/log` is simply the default location, you can change this via `/etc/syslog.conf`.

If you do change the location, make sure to also update the config for `logrotate` to point to the new location as well, otherwise your log files will grow unchecked. [hint: `/etc/logrotate.conf` and `/etc/logrotate.d/`]

Comment: On recent Debian and Ubuntu versions, logging for several facilities is actually handled by rsyslog. (Configured in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and `/etc/rsyslog.d/*`.)

Answer (score 2):

When an "application logs to syslog", it doesn't "store it's logs in `/var/log`" just like that.  What it does is that it logs messages to something called a facility and a severity level.

The available facilities are:

```
auth, authpriv, daemon, cron, ftp, lpr, kern, mail, news, syslog, user, uucp, local0, local1, local2, local3, local4, local5, local6, local7
```

The available severities are:

```
emergency, alert, critical, error, warning, notice, info, debug
```

For example, the Linux kernel sends its messages (or "logs" its messages) to the facility called `kern`, and uses various severities to indicate the severity of the message; the Linux authentication mechanism logs to `auth` and `authpriv`; `cron` logs to `cron`, and so on. Other applications can be programmed/designed to log to the "local" facilities, `local0` - `local7`, using different severity levels.

Now, the syslog daemon has a configuration file, usually `/etc/syslog.conf`. In this config file, we define where to save or send these messages. Some sample configuration lines from `/etc/syslog.conf` look like this:

```
kern.*                          /var/log/kern.log
mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err
*.*                             /var/log/syslog
```

The first line tells the syslog daemon to log `kern.*` messages (meaning facility `kern` and the `*` meaning all severities) to the file `/var/log/kern.log`, the second saves the `mail` facility and `err` severity messages to `/var/log/mail.err`, and the third logs everything to `/var/log/syslog`.

So, to answer your question, a message logs to a facility and severity, and the `syslog.conf` file is the one that decides where it's saved. But generally, the default configuration of `syslog` is that it saves to files under `/var/log`.